# Recursive multiplication in prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, multiplication

New to prolog.

edit: using swi-prolog

I want to recursively do what the multiplication method already does in prolog without actually using the multiplication method.

The algorithm I want to implement it looks something like:

```
    multn(N1, N2, output){
    if (n2 <=0) return output;
    else
        multn(N1, (N2-1), output + N1)
    }
```

Ex: 4*4 = 4+4+4+4 = 16

edit*: only passing in positive numbers for this algo.

my knowledge db looks like:

```
    multn(Num1, 0, Result) :- Result is 0.

    multn(Num1, Num2, Result) :- 
        NewNum2 = Num2 - 1, 
        multn(Num1, NewNum2, NewResult),
        Result is Num1 + NewResult.
```

However, when I call:

```
    ?- multn(2,2,R).
```

It goes on forever, why is this not stopping at the above base case?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: As a beginner, start with [tag:successor-arithmetics]. Then switch to `library(clpfd)`. Recommended book: Art of Prolog

Comment: Ive been reading through successor-arithmetics and clpfd and am still struggling to grasp it, if you could offer any insight into solving just this specific problem, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please read above tag! The very first/popular question is exactly about this!

Comment: what's the reason you haven't written `NewNum2 is Num2 - 1` ?

Comment: Still new to prolog, that fixed it, what exactly is the difference between = and is? Doesn't = mean bind? similar to another language like java?

Comment: we can use **!** in  `multn(_, 0, 0):- !.`  to stop rebuild other results  ?

Comment: Using `!/0` destroys relational properties of this predicate: Always also try the most general query, in this case: `?- multn(X, Y, Z).`. I agree with what @false said. For the case of multplication, I recommend to start with CLP(FD) constraints right away, since `s/1` terms quickly become quite hard to use.

Comment: `is/2` *evaluates arithmetic expressions* and unifies the first argument with the evaluation of the expression given in the second argument. Quite different. `=/2` is the *unification* operation. It attempts to unify the first and second arguments as Prolog terms.

Answer (score 3):

For integer arithmetic, use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraints. All serious Prolog systems provide them. For example, for SICStus Prolog, put `:- use_module(library(clpfd))` in your initialisation file to make CLP(FD) constraints available in all your programs.

Using CLP(FD) constraints and some small modifications, your initial program becomes:

```
int_int_prod(_, 0, 0).
int_int_prod(Num1, Num2, Result) :- 
        NewNum2 #= Num2 - 1, 
        int_int_prod(Num1, NewNum2, NewResult),
        Result #= Num1 + NewResult.
```

And now the point: You obviously meant your clauses to be mutually *exclusive*.

Insert `Num2 #> 0` at an appropriate place to do that!

Comment: if we add `Num2 #> 0` in the appropriate place, which is suitable for these  conditions : `Num2 #> 0 -> ` or `Num2 #> 0 ,`

Comment: `(->)/2` almost always leads to declarative problems: It can only be safely used if its argument is ground; otherwise, you risk losing solutions by committing prematurely. In this case, simply add `Num #> 0` as one of the goals: It is a necessary condition for this clause to apply.